# How to commit only a message to GIT?

Tags: git

Suppose that I have been working on a branch and have committed my work but want to 
add a message in the logs of what is next on the todo list for the branch.  Times 
I might want to do this include:

- Switching branches to work on something else - need to remind myself of what to do next
- Weekend
- Other

Is it possible to commit to git without committing any files?  Anyother way to word this: Is it possible to commit only a message to GIT?

Comment: See `git help notes`.

Comment: @chepner That should be the right answer, as this is precisely what `git notes` were designed for - it can be done with empty commits and/or tags (annotated or not), but that isn't what those features were meant for...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes.  It is possible.  I can never remember how to do this and always need to Google (so I am writting a Q/A in hope that this will help me to remember).

The command is:

```
git commit --allow-empty --only
```

The doc for `--allow-empty` reads:

> Usually recording a commit that has the exact same tree as its sole
> parent commit is a mistake, and the command prevents you from making
> such a commit. This option bypasses the safety, and is primarily for
> use by foreign SCM interface scripts.

Doc makes sense but isn't easy to search for.

Comment: I use --allow-empty quite a bit, usually when I make a new branch to explain why the branch was created.

Comment: I can't figure out why this isn't in the list of options in `git commit --help`.  I can never remember what the option is, so I always need to return here to find it.  Probably 30% of the 140 page views are from me.

Answer (score 12):

You might also consider use an annotated tag instead.  You could then remove the tag later without having to rewrite history.  To me this makes more sense than adding empty commits to your history.

```
git tag -a TODO-feature-foo -m "next I'm going to..."
git push origin :TODO-feature-foo
```

Once no longer needed:

```
git push origin :TODO-feature-foo
```

Comment: This was perfect for my needs, as I wanted to include both a start/end tag for a repo cleanup

Answer (score 10):

Note: if you have *staged* changed, but want to create an empty commit with only a message, then you need (with Git 2.12, Q1 2017):

```
git commit --only --allow-empty -m "my message"
```

"`git commit --allow-empty --only`" (no pathspec) with dirty index ought to be an acceptable way to create a new commit that does not change any paths, but it was forbidden, perhaps because nobody needed it so far.

See [commit beb635c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/beb635ca9ced5cd8f0eb5d2def9468f14bd243bc) (09 Dec 2016), and [commit 319d835](https://github.com/git/git/commit/319d835240b752b94ccb67f6515759824955937b) (02 Dec 2016) by [Andreas Krey (`apk`)](https://github.com/apk).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3aead1c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3aead1cad7a9a35534b86763bbe8c97dfd3f1a03), 19 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/319d835240b752b94ccb67f6515759824955937b): make `--only --allow-empty` work without paths
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andreas Krey</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> `--only` is implied when paths are present, and required them unless `--amend`.
> But with `--allow-empty`, it should be allowed as well: it is the only way to create an empty commit in the presence of staged changes.